# Prove that d is a continuous real valued function on $M \times M$

Tags: metric-spaces, product-space

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space. Let $M \times M$ be the product space, where $d$ is defined (earlier in the book as ) $d((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))=d_1(x_1,y_1)+d_2(x_2,y_2)$ where $d_1$ and $d_2$ are metrics on $M_1$ and $M_2$, respectively.

I must prove that $d$ is a continuous real valued function.

I am very confused about the notation, an I supposed to show that $M \times M$ is the set or $M_1 \times M_2$ is the set in supposed to use? I guess it doesn't really matter but it would really help me.

Can someone help me out on starting the proof?

I know I must choose my delta to be $\varepsilon/2$ since I have two points, but my question is how will some of the notation look like?

[image: this is the exceed use I am being asked to do 12]

[image: this is where they define the product metric space]

Comment: Well you are in the case $M_1 = M_2.$

Comment: @zhw. In that case, do we have 2d(x,y)?

Comment: No, you have $d((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))=d_1(x_1,y_1)+d_1(x_2,y_2).$

Comment: @mjo which book is this

Comment: What is the name of the book. Is it from Foundations of Mathematical Analysis By Richard Johnsonbaugh, W.E. Pfaffenberger, [page 140](https://books.google.com/books?id=X_6NMZVMidsC&pg=PA140)? (I think that adding source of the problem is an information which should be contained in a post.)

Comment: Yes , that is the correct textbook!

Answer (score 0):

Let $d$ denote the metric on $M$ .

Let $\rho$ denote the metric on $M\times M$ wich is defined as $$\rho\left(\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right),\left(x_{1},y_{1}\right)\right)=d\left(x_{0},x_{1}\right)+d\left(y_{0},y_{1}\right)$$

Then it can be shown that $$\left|d\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right)-d\left(x_{1},y_{1}\right)\right|\leq\rho\left(\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right),\left(x_{1},y_{1}\right)\right)\tag1$$

This on base of $$d\left(x_{1},y_{1}\right)\leq d\left(x_{1},x_{0}\right)+d\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right)+d\left(y_{0},y_{1}\right)=\rho\left(\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right),\left(x_{1},y_{1}\right)\right)+d\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right)$$
and: $$d\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right)\leq d\left(x_{0},x_{1}\right)+d\left(x_{1},y_{1}\right)+d\left(y_{1},y_{0}\right)=\rho\left(\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right),\left(x_{1},y_{1}\right)\right)+d\left(x_{1},y_{1}\right)$$

To be shown is that function $d:M\times M\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous
when $\mathbb{R}$ is equipped with its usual topology.

The topology on $\mathbb{R}$ has the intervals $\left(-\infty,a\right)$ and $(a,\infty)$ as subbasis, so it is enough to prove that  $\left\{ \left(x,y\right)\in M\times M\mid d\left(x,y\right)<a\right\}$ and $\left\{ \left(x,y\right)\in M\times M\mid d\left(x,y\right)>a\right\}$
are open sets in $M\times M$ for every $a\in\mathbb R$.

That means that for any pair $\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right)$ with $d\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right)<a$
some $\epsilon>0$ must be found such that $\rho\left(\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right),\left(x_1,y_1\right)\right)<\epsilon\Rightarrow d\left(x_1,y_1\right)<a$.

And likewise that for any pair $\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right)$ with $d\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right)>a$
some $\epsilon>0$ must be found such that $\rho\left(\left(x_{0},y_{0}\right),\left(x_1,y_1\right)\right)<\epsilon\Rightarrow d\left(x_1,y_1\right)>a$.

This can be done by use of (1).

Comment: Why does R have to have the integral (-infinity,a) as its subasis? We haven't learned anything about that yet.

Comment: Firstly: I made a mistake (mixed up continuity with measurability), and repaired. The intervals $(-\infty,b)$ *together with* the intervals $(a,\infty)$ form a subbasis. Intersections give intervals $(a,b)$ and these form a basis.